# How do you say the total amount of time that has been spent in a job position?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I'd like to know what's the best word to describe someone that has been in a certain job position. For example, if I was hired in January and now it's March, my _______ (*word I'd like to know*) is 3 months.

In Spanish, I'd say *antigüedad*.
Searching for this word in English it's translated as **antiquity** but it is defined as:

> The ancient past, especially the period before the Middle Ages. Great Age.

So saying: *My antiquity in the position is 3 months* seems to be inaccurate, isn't it?

Please advise.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Tenure***

In one of its meanings:

a. The act, fact, manner, or condition of holding something in one's possession, as real estate or an office; occupation.
b. A period during which something is held.

[(American Heritage Dictionary)](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=tenure)

Examples of use:

*Average job **tenure** has remained unchanged, subject to cyclical variation, for the last 25 years. The average duration of a job in progress is around five years.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=EkYsXC4stGAC&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&lpg=PP102&dq=tenure%20at%20job&pg=PP102#v=onepage&q=tenure%20at%20job&f=false)
*Why are Wages Upward Sloping with **Tenure?** … We might expect the hazard rate from jobs to decrease nonmonotonically with **tenure**.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=qO_z61jsVwYC&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&lpg=PA34&dq=%22We%20might%20expect%20the%20hazard%20rate%20from%20jobs%20to%20decrease%20nonmonotonically%20with%20tenure.%22&pg=PA34#v=onepage&q=%22We%20might%20expect%20the%20hazard%20rate%20from%20jobs%20to%20decrease%20nonmonotonically%20with%20tenure.%22&f=false)

Comment: _Seniority_ is what I meant in my question, but I didn't know the `tenure` word either. It will be useful for me to remember too. Thanks for your time to post the answer.

Comment: @Metafaniel Sure, no problem. Note, however, that you can't really say *my seniority is 3 months,* but you **can** say *my tenure is 3 months.* The literal definition of *seniority* is *a privileged status attained by length of continuous service (as in a company)*. For examples of usage of *seniority,* see [here](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/seniority).

Comment: That's an important note you did... It seems to be in Spanish there's no difference as we use the same word for both definitions so at first thought it seemed `seniority` was the word I needed. The definition you gave about `tenure` seemed more similar to `tenencia` in Spanish (as in "this is my possession / ownership").

Because you say the correct way to say it is: "my tenure is 3 months" (time that has given me a state of seniority in my company), then yours is the correct answer. Do I get it right?? Thanks again.

Comment: Please clarify if I get it right to change the correct answer to this one instead.

Comment: @Metafaniel The things is, what one would probably **actually** say in everyday life is something like *I have been [with the company]/[at my job] for 3 months.* The word *tenure* in that context is rather formal, and is most commonly used in rather formal contexts (e.g *The median tenure of an engineer at this company is seven years.*) However, the question of formality aside, it is certainly **good English** to say things like *Although his tenure was only eighteen months, he oversaw the transfer of the GSC from the Interior Department to the new Mines Department.*

Comment: @Metafaniel Note that, unlike *seniority*, the word *tenure* (in this sense of it) does not imply the attainment of any special privileges. On the other hand, the word *seniority* does imply privileges (or a lack of them if you say that someone doesn't have seniority, or doesn't have *sufficient* seniority). But to associate seniority to some time duration, one needs to use a different construction, e.g. *An additional week of vacation will be given to workers with over 30 years of seniority.*

Comment: @Metafaniel In your original question, you didn't indicate that the word should indicate the attainment of special privileges that go with the length of employment (except possibly to those who know with precision what the Spanish word *antigüedad* means in this context). If that is in fact what you meant, you should modify the text of your question. Also, I would say that in that case, probably no English word would at the same time express the meaning you want **and** be able to be used in your sample sentence exactly as you phrased it.

Comment: @Metafaniel Of course, you can say things like *Once his tenure exceeded ten years, Mike finally had enough seniority to be able to decline to work at night.*

Comment: Yours is the correct answer then, as I only wanted to know the word to express the total amount of time someone has been working in a company (i.e. _The median tenure of an engineer at this company is seven years._ and _his tenure was only eighteen months_) privileges aside (1 month,3 months,5 years,etc.) as a time measure.

`Antigüedad` is more general. It is equally used as _antiquity, tenure_ and _seniority_. No differences exist and it is understandable and used equally in those contexts.

Thanks again for your useful comments: https://media.giphy.com/media/u4aVBa0M8LqhIOCMem/giphy.gif

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking for:

***[Seniority:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/seniority)***

> the advantage that you get by working for a company for a long time:
>
> - In future, promotion will be based on merit not seniority.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: Thank you for your time for that answer, but `tenure` is what I actually meant (see comments with @linguisticturn) Thanks anyway. Greetings.

Comment: @Metafaniel This is the better word for a present-tense sentence. *I **have** [X time] of seniority.* It's an ongoing situation. But if I were to say *I have a tenure of [X time]*, that would imply that it's a temporary position that expires after that amount of time, which you have yet to complete. In the question, you ask about *has* been, which is something present and ongoing, without a fixed end. You don't use *tenure* for that.